# I have an excel workbook that automatically runs a macro when it is opened. Is there a way to pass parameters into this?

Tags: python, excel

I'm currently writing a Python script that opens excel, runs a macro, and then saves it. Because I was having trouble with Openpyxl and XLWings calling specific macros, I decided to just automatically have the macro run when opening up excel. However, is there a way to pass in parameters from the Python script for the automatically-running macro to take?

Comment: just pass some value to a cell and call that cell in your vba macro

Comment: That's smart, thanks a lot!